# Get a mask of len of True/False array

Tags: python, numpy

This code works:

```
all_historic_data = pd.DataFrame()

percent_of_data = 0.8
#create train and test sets
#this methodology will randomly select percent_of_data of our data

msk = np.random.rand(len(all_historic_data)) < percent_of_data
train = all_historic_data[msk]
test = all_historic_data[~msk]
```

However, if I don't want a random number and I try this:

```
msk = range(len(all_historic_data)) < percent_of_data
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'range' and 'float'
```

How do I get a fixed `array` where the number of entries of `True` to `False` ratio is exactly `percent_of_data`

Comment: try [`np.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) instead of `range`. But also, just make it directly? `n = len(all_historic_data)`, `msk = np.zeros(n).astype('bool')`, `msk[:int(percent_of_data * n)] = True` ?

Comment: Do you want to randomly sample a given percentage of a population?

Comment: You can use `random.choice` : `np.random.choice([True,False],len(all_historic_data), p=[0.8,0.2])`.

Comment: you say 'this code works', but this line 'msk = np.random.rand(len(all_historic_data)) < percent_of_data' give error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'random'`

Comment: See edited post. all_historic_data = pd.DataFrame()

Answer (score 1):

I will assume `all_historic_data` is a vector.

If you just want to completely have the same result every time, one potential solution is to set the seed, so the "randomly" generated numbers will actually always be the same. You would do this as follows:

```
np.random.seed(10) # write any number you like
a = np.random.rand(100)
np.random.seed(10) # write any number you like
b = np.random.rand(100)
print(a == b)
```

Since you set a seed, the "random" component of it is gone - you will always get the same figures.

Indeed, the output is:

```
[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True]
```

NB: `len(all_historic_data)` is an int, so `range(len(all_historic_data))` is a range object, holding values 0, 1, ..., len(all_historic_data) - 1. For example, if you run

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
```

Then, the output will be

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Therefore, you can notice all of these numbers, except the first one, will be less that 0.8. If you use this to make a train set, then there will be only one observation in your train set.

If you still want to compare numbers in a range object with a float, using `np.arange`, as mentioned by @Dan, might help.